# Ampersand issue in excel export from MySQL PHP Report

Tags: excel, export, ampersand

We have an online **MySQL DataBase** using **PHP** as the serverside language.

We are building this DataBase from an **Access Database** which is currently being used.

The process is to take the Access Tables, run them through some JSON processes (I am not a SME on this by any means) which converts them I gather into MySQL tables for use.
Both the Access DB and the MySQL DB have export to excel functionality for reports.

When running a report and exporting to Excel,  the download from the **online application** looks like this  "Bus &amp(semicolon) Truck" while the same report run from the **access** data base correctly looks like this  "Bus & Truck"

Note the word semicolon is used because if i just type in an actual semicolon - the bit you will actually read comes up as an "&"  and not "&amp[semicolon] which is what I am writing in the body section of this question.
In other words stack overflow is doing the opposite - as i write  & a m p; (ignore the spaces) it is rendering it in the thing you are reading as an "&"

This is consistent across all columns and fields where we have an ampersand in the field. It appears the online export changes an  "&"  into "& amp;"  (without the space).

On the UI the online application correctly renders  "Bus & Truck"  and on the Access DB, the UI also correctly renders "Bus & Truck".
So it would appear something goes wrong in the export to excel process.

Answer (score -1):

Set

Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

Click the below link for reference.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1138814.aspx?+Problem+in+special+characters+ehen+exporting+to+excel+in+Asp+Net+C+